# Generating new columns grouping dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spyder

I'm trying to implement new columns in my dataframe with the following form:

```
Client_id    Product_a

1            1 

1            2

1            1

1            0

2            1

2            0

2            3

2            1
```

So...what I want to do is three new columns (total_buy, total_sell and total_operations). In those new columns I wanna calculate the total amount of buys,sells and the total of the operations for each client_id. Each client_id appears at least once and maximum 24 times in the table.
So my output should look like this (for the sample showed above):

```
Client_id    A_buy    A_sell   A_operations

1            2        2        4
2            4        3        7
```

I was using groupby with different function as sum/mean/min/max and they are very useful but now I'd like to try this new approach. Actually I have around 52k clients and 12 different products but I can not realize how to approach this new task.
Th total amount of rows in my data frame is around 600k and each client has at least 1 occurrence and maximum 24 (I have 2 years of data)

There is any build-in function to approach this task?
Any suggestion to approach this issue?

Thanks for help in advice!

Comment: What is the relationship between `Product_a` and `A_buy`, `A_sell` and `A_operations`?

Comment: For each row with the same id_client shows the final amount of the product_a for each month so...for the client_id = 1 following the sample in the original post, for the first month he bought 1 product, in the next month he bought another one, in the 3rd month he sold 1 product and in the last month he sold another one. So client_id = 1 bought 2 times and sold 2 times and the same logic for client_id = 2. I hope I have clarified the problem.

Comment: The DataFrame you posted only has `Client_id` and `Product_a` columns. How are we to know the months and if he bought or sold the product?

Comment: If client_id = 1 has 20 rows means that this client was 20 months, each row with the same id shows the final amount in the month.                                  To be more clear... if the values for 10 months are the same for example client_id = 5 and he bought in the 3rd month 1 product and he never sold the output will be a_buy = 1, a_sell = 0 a_operations = 1. I have grouped the table using: df1.groupby(['id_cliente']).sum/max/min

Answer (score 2):

Let's try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Client_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'Product_a':[1,2,1,0,1,0,3,1]})

#Define action based on diff previous record fill first record with first value in group
df_out = df.assign(action=df.groupby('Client_id')['Product_a']\
                            .apply(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(x.iloc[0])))

#Classify buy or sell based of positive or negative action
df_out['buys'] = np.where(df_out.action.gt(0), df_out.action, 0)
df_out['sells'] = np.where(df_out.action.lt(0), df_out.action.mul(-1), 0)

#Lastly, groupby and sum records by client
df_out.groupby('Client_id')[['buys', 'sells']].sum().eval('operations = buys + sells')\
      .add_prefix('A_').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Client_id  A_buys  A_sells  A_operations
0          1     2.0      2.0           4.0
1          2     4.0      3.0           7.0
```

Comment: @WinterZ. if this answer helped you, would you [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).  I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I have developed one solution for this task using Pandas, bcause of the nature of the dataset's form pandas was quicker than an numpy implementation. Your solution works very well and solves the task very well but pandas with shift method is quite quicker.

Comment: @WinterZ Do you mind pasting back your solution using diff in the comments here.  I'd love to see what you ending up using.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My pandas code works using some simple filters and its serialized for all products in my database... if someone needs to use it only on a simple column you do not need the for loop just change the str(product) for the column name.

```
for product in productos:
dfloop[str(product) + '_buys'] = dfloop[product]
dfloop[str(product) + '_sells'] = 0

dfloop.loc[dfloop["id_cliente"] == dfloop["id_cliente"].shift(1),[str(product) + '_buys']] \
    = dfloop[product] - dfloop[product].shift(1)

dfloop.loc[dfloop[str(product) + '_buys'] < 0 ,[str(product) + '_sells']] = -dfloop[str(product) + '_buys']
dfloop.loc[dfloop[str(product) + '_buys'] < 0 ,[str(product) + '_buys']] = 0
```

The code is so simple, First of all Im making the new buy and sell columns for each product in my db then I use shift function from pandas...first for check if there is a id change and then to rest the product difference among the rows.

The last two lines of code just recalculate correctly the sums of the buys and sells. It works correctly for any db only with few changes..
I hope this code will help someone in the future.